# Getting System.TypeIntialization exception: The type intializer for Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection threw an exception

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, exception

This error occurred with 64 bit version Oracle.DataAcess but it is working 32 bit version.
I am connecting from c# application to oracle database.
Below code giving exception

```
Using(OracleConnection obj=new OracleConnection())
{
}
```

Exception details:
System.TypeIntialization exception: The type intializer for Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection threw an exception

Any Idea what is the reason - Help me on this how to fix this

Comment: "Any Idea what is the reason" - that will be contained in the exception details. There should be an inner exception that shows what caused the TypeInitializationException. I suspect it may well be a matter of the wrong native libraries being loaded, but we're just guessing until we know what's in the inner exception.

Comment: Inner Exception :Provider is not compatible with version of oracle client

Comment: Right, well that sounds like something you can investigate then.